# Apply style to a MenuItem populated from an Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to populate a MenuItem from my menu item list, in doing so I'm able to get the data properly but the styling is getting messed up, it's as if there is an overlay with my current style and the default menu item style

Please have a look at the images:

Working
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWIPI.png)]

Not Working
[image]

This is my list of sample items in the Menu

```cs
public IEnumerable<String> MenuItems { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "ItemA", "ItemB" };*
```

This is the main code

```
<Border Background="#fff">
     <Menu>
         <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemDropDownBaseStyle}" 
                   Header="Hello"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
             <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                       <!-- doesn't work -->
                       <MenuItem Header="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" />
                   </DataTemplate>
             </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>

             <!-- works -->
             <!-- <MenuItem Header="ItemA" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" /> -->
             <!-- <MenuItem Header="ItemB" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" /> -->
         </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
  </Border>
```

This is my styling for MenuItem dropdown and each container item within

```
<Window.Resources>

        <Color x:Key="White">#ffffff</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrushWhite" Color="{StaticResource White}" />

        <Color x:Key="Black">#000000</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrushBlack" Color="{StaticResource Black}" />

        <Color x:Key="Viking">#67cfdf</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrushViking" Color="{StaticResource Viking}" />

        <Color x:Key="MidnightBlue">#003966</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrushMidnightBlue" Color="{StaticResource MidnightBlue}" />

        <Color x:Key="CongressBlue">#014984</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrushCongressBlue" Color="{StaticResource CongressBlue}" />

        <Color x:Key="DullLavender">#8ca5e0</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrushDullLavender" Color="{StaticResource DullLavender}" />

        <Style x:Key="MenuItemDropDownBaseStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Padding="12, 7, 12, 7" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                              TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushBlack}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>

                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">

                                <Border CornerRadius="5" 
                                    Width="190"
                                    Padding="0, 5, 0, 5"
                                    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushViking}">
                                    <!--<ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">-->

                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <!--<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />-->
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
                                </Border>

                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ContentBorder" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushViking}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="ContentBorder" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushViking}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="MenuItemBaseStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" Height="32">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentP"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushWhite}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Border x:Name="SideHighlight"
                                    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}, Path=Height}"
                                    Width="4"
                                    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushCongressBlue}"
                                    CornerRadius="0, 50, 50, 0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="ContentP" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrushMidnightBlue}" />
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="SideHighlight" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ItemBorder" Value="blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

I tried applying in the ItemContainerStyle my custom style but doesn't work anyhow, I know I've missed something here but not able to figure out

Comment: To improve the performance, you should exclusively bind to collections that implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, for example `ObservableCollection<T>`. This is especially crucial if the source collection instance is expected to change or if the source object is expected to have a limited lifetime (shorter than the application's lifetime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MenuItem` is a an `ItemsControl` (a `HeaderdItemsControl`). As such it automatically generates an item container to host the content. The content is the data item.
This container is itself of type `MenuItem`. `MenuItem` is an item container that can host child item containers.

Your properly behaving example omits the automatic item container generation because you were adding those containers explicitly:

```xml
<MenuItem>
  <MenuItem /> <!-- Explicit child container -->
</MenuItem>
```

The "non-working" example defines an `DataTemplate` and the child elements are added implicitly via binding items to the `MenuItem.ItemsSource`: the parent `MenuItem` will generate an item container of type `MenuItem` and sets the data item as its content. Then the content's visuals are defined by the `DataTemplate` which in your case defines another `MenuItem`.

The result is a `MenuItem` (item container) that has an `MenuItem` (from `DataTemplate`) as content. This leads to the undesired layout.
In other words, the problem is not the `Style` but the `DataTemplate`.

To fix this, remove the `MenuItem` from the `DataTemplate`. Instead provide an element that hosts the representation of the data item for example a `TextBlock`:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Although this will make it work, the `DataTemplate` itself is pretty much redundant. It only displays a `string` value (the source collection is a collection of `string` items).
The `HeaderedItemsControl` will create a similar content template automatically by default.
Therefore, the following code is sufficient to show a list of menu items as child items of a `MenuItem`:

```xml
<!-- Will automatically show "Item A" and "Item B" as child menu items -->
<MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemDropDownBaseStyle}" 
          Header="Hello"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" />
```

You only have to define a `DataTemplate` if the content layout is complex.

To specify a `Style` for the chld items explicitly, simply set the `ItemsControl.ItemContainer` property:

```xml
<!-- Will automatically show "Item A" and "Item B" as child menu items -->
<MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemDropDownBaseStyle}" 
          Header="Hello"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" />
```

In case of a more complex data item, you can control the property which should be displayed as the header by setting the `ItemsControl.DispalyMemberPath`:

```xml
<!-- Will automatically show "Item A" and "Item B" as child menu items -->
<MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemDropDownBaseStyle}" 
          Header="Hello"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}"
          DispalyMemberPath="NameOfSomePropertyOnTheItemThatShouldBeTheHeader" />
```

If your `MenuItem` is more complex than showing a simple text header then you have to define a `DataTemplate` or define a `MenuItem.Header` object using the XAML object notation (`<MenuItem.Header> ... </MenuItem.Header>`):

**ItemModel.cs**

```cs
// TODO::Implement INotifyPropertyChanged even if properties won't change!
class ItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Value for the menu item's header
  public string Title { get; }

  // Value that binds to a CheckBox in the menu item
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<!-- 
     Dynamic MenuItem generation using data binding (using ItemsSource).
-->
<Menu>

  <!-- 
       The Style assigned to ItemContainerStyle property is 
       automatically applied to all generated child containers (nested MenuItem elements). 

       Bind ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection<ItemModel> 
  -->
  <MenuItem Header="Parent of Generated Checkable Entries" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemModels}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}"> 
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="local:ItemModel">
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

```xml
<!-- Static (inline) MenuItem generation by adding MenuItem elements explicitly  -->
<Menu>

  <!-- 
       The Style assigned to ItemContainerStyle property is 
       automatically applied to all children (nested MenuItem elements). 
       If a child MenuItem element has a value assigned to its Style property, 
       then this local value is used instead of the value from the ItemContainerStyle property.
  -->
  <MenuItem Header="Parent of Checkable Entries"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}"> 

    <!-- 
         The style assigned to the Style property is 
         exclusively applied to the current MenuItem. 
         In addition, this local value overrides the Style value
         assigned to the parent's ItemContainerStyle property.
    -->
    <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}">
      <MenuItem.Header>
        <CheckBox Content="Explicit menu item"
                  IsChecked="True" />
      </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>

    <!-- Alternative declaration using an item model -->
    <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}">
      <MenuItem.Header>
        <local:ItemModel Title="Explicit menu item"
                         IsSelected="True" />
      </MenuItem.Header>
      <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:ItemModel">
          <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was really helpful ! just one more thing if I need to bind few more properties of the MenuItem like IsChecked ... from my class how should i do that ?

Comment: I have updated the examples to show how to define a `DataTemplate` to layout the menu item.

Comment: I have added more alternatives to the example so that you can pick what meets your requirements best.

Comment: thanks again, but how do I use the styling I created for the menu item, like what u mentioned in this case as well the checkbox will be inside a menu item container resulting in the overlapped styles

Comment: There are two cases: 1) a Style that applies directly to the current `MenuItem` (local) --> Simply assign the "MenuItemBaseStyle" to the `MenuItem.Style` property of the current `MenuItem`. 2) a `Style` that applies to all the children of a parent `MenuItem` --> Simply assign the "MenuItemBaseStyle" to the `MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle` property of the parent  `MenuItem`. I have updated the examples to show both cases.